# To generate dynamic List in Action on Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

In my Action on Google #AOG App, based on the use input the number of items in the List is dyanmic. Can you please let me know how to generate the List Dynamically in "actions-on-google"

My Data Structure : "filteredKural" is array of objects with parameters "kuralNumber" and "tamilKural". created an itemsObject and assigned it to the List items parameter but it is not working. Can you please suggest any alternate ways through which i can generate the items value dynamically.

The below code is not working.

```
    for (i=0; i<filteredKural.length;i++)
    {
    let keyName = `Kural ${filteredKural[i].kuralNumber}`; 
    itemsObject[keyName] = { title:filteredKural[i].kuralNumber, description:filteredKural[i].tamiKural};
    }
    /* console.log(itemsObject) // Output of the itemsObject 
    { 'Kural 11':
    { title: '11',description:'வான்நின்று உலகம் வழங்கி வருதலால் தான்அமிழ்தம் என்றுணரற் பாற்று.' },
    'Kural 12':
     { title: '12',description:'துப்பார்க்குத் துப்பாய துப்பாக்கித் துப்பார்க்குத் துப்பாய தூஉம் மழை.' },
      'Kural 13':
      { title: '13',description:'விண்இன்று பொய்ப்பின் விரிநீர் வியனுலகத்து உள்நின்று உடற்றும் பசி.' },
      'Kural 14':
      { title: '14',description: 'ஏரின் உழாஅர் உழவர் புயல்என்னும் வாரி வளங்குன்றிக் கால்.' },
       'Kural 15':
      { title: '15',description:'கெடுப்பதூஉம் கெட்டார்க்குச் சார்வாய்மற் றாங்கே எடுப்பதூஉம் எல்லாம் மழை.' },
      */ 

      conv.ask('The list of Kural');
      conv.ask ( new List ({
      title: 'kural List', 
       items : itemsObject, // this is not working 
                          }));
```

Comment: Can you update your question to elaborate on what you mean by "not working"? Is it producing an error? Not showing the list? Not showing what you expect?

Comment: I am getting an exception in the simulator and the List is not getting Displayed

Comment: Please update your question to show the error in the simulator and the text from the "request", "response", and "debug" tabs.